# Notation for derivatives at a certain point

Tags: notation, mathematica

Is the notation for values of a derivative at some point that I used in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/572272/19661) commonly accepted and understandable? Is there a more preferred one?

For those who familiar with *Mathematica* — I used the notation
$$\left[\frac{\partial J_\nu(x)}{\partial\nu}\right]_{\nu=1/2}$$
to represent an equivalent of *Mathematica* expression [`Derivative[1, 0][BesselJ][1/2, x]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Derivative.html) or, equivalently, [`Function[ν, BesselJ[ν, x]]'[1/2]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a general answer, but

- It is perfectly understandable to me. And I think most seasoned mathematicians will not mistake it for anything else.
- I would personally usually use the vertical bar for restriction or evaluation, like
  $$ \left. \frac{\partial J_\nu(x)}{\partial \nu}\right|_{\nu = \frac12} $$
  to express what you wrote. But that is just one convention that one sees used sometimes in PDEs and geometry.

Comment: Is the form $\left.\partial_\nu J_\nu(x)\right|_{\nu=1/2}$ okay as well?

Comment: If I see what you wrote in the comment, I would most likely arrive at the correct conclusion as to what you mean. So in that sense I think it is ok.